# License Not Needed for Fishing in County of Residence

Tags: united-states, fishing

It seems pretty clear but I would like to make sure that I don't need a license or permit to Catch and Release in Florida, in the county that I live in. According to [Florida Fish and Wildlife Conservation Commission](http://myfwc.com/license/recreational/do-i-need-a-license/),

> You do not need a recreational hunting, freshwater fishing or
>   saltwater fishing license or a *Florida waterfowl, migratory bird,
>   deer, turkey, snook, spiny lobster, archery season, crossbow season,
>   muzzle loading season permit or management area permit if…
>
> You hunt or freshwater fish in your county of residence on your
>   homestead or the homestead of your spouse or minor child, or if you
>   are a minor child hunting or freshwater fishing on the homestead of
>   your parent.

So I can fish everywhere in my county without a license or permit?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The section you've quoted **does not** say you can fish everywhere in your home county without a license.  The exemption applies only when you are on your homestead (or your spouse's, kid's, etc.).  *Note that "homestead" usually has a particular legal meaning, so don't assume it's just a way of saying "residence" or "property".*

However, if you read further down [the page](http://myfwc.com/license/recreational/do-i-need-a-license/), you will find the "cane pole" exemption (meaning no reel allowed):

> You are a resident who is fishing with live or natural bait, using poles or lines **that are not equipped with a fishing-line-retrieval mechanism**, and you are fishing for noncommercial purposes in your home county.  However, you must have a valid fishing license to fish by any method in a fish management area.

Comment: I must have read that at least three times and then read it when posting here still thinking it said county of residence or your homestead instead of on homestead. I knew it was too good to be true :P